# Show the $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So we want to show that the interior of any set $A$ is open.

We will denote $\operatorname{int}(A)$ as the interior of $A$ which is the set of all interior points of $A$.

I know in order to prove this we must show that if $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$, then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x + \delta)\subset\operatorname{int}(A)$.

Proof:

Let $x\in \operatorname{int}(A)$
.  Then by definition of $\operatorname{int}(A)$ we know that there exists $\delta>0$, such that $(x-\delta, x +\delta)\subset A$.  So we know what to show this interval is a subset of $A$.  So, we want to show $(x-\delta, x + \delta)\subset \operatorname{int}(A)$.

So let $y \in (x-\delta, x + \delta)$.

Now here is what I'm having trouble with:

I know we should let $\epsilon$ equal the min of something.  Then $(y-\delta, y + \delta)\subset (x- \delta, x + \delta)\subset \operatorname{int}(A)$. And then $y$ would be an interior point of $A$ and since $y$ is arbitrary then $(x- \delta, x + \delta)\subset \operatorname{int}(A)$. Thus, $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open.

Does this sound about right?

Not really sure what the $\epsilon$ should equal. I know it should equal the minimum of some interval.  Could you explain this proof more to me? Very confused.

Comment: If you know a little topology, $int(A)$ is, almost by definition, open.

Comment: I need a proof of this

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$If $x\in\int(A)$, then there is a $\delta_x>0$ such that $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\subseteq A$. You’d like to show that this interval $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\subseteq\int(A)$. Suppose that $y\in(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$. Let

$$\epsilon=\min\{y-(x-\delta_x),(x+\delta_x)-y\}\;,$$

and show that $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\subseteq(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\subseteq A$; it follows that $y\in\int(A)$ and hence that $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\subseteq\int(A)$.

A rough sketch should help you see why I’m choosing $\epsilon$ that way, if it isn’t immediately clear.

I’ve written this on the assumption that your definition of *open set* is that $U$ is open if for each $x\in U$ there is a $\delta_x>0$ such that $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\subseteq U$. There are other (equivalent) definitions that would make the work even easier.

Comment: If I have to show that int(A) is open wouldn't I have to show that (x- $\delta$, x + $\delta$)$\subset$ int(A)? Not just (x- $\delta$, x + $\delta$)$\subset$ A

Comment: @Diego: Sorry: I was interrupted and lost track of what I was doing. Hang on a minute and I’ll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x \in A^\circ$, you know there exists $\delta>0$, such that $U=(x-\delta, x +\delta)\subset A$. Then we have $U \subset A^\circ$.

To see  this, let $y \in U$. Let $\eta = \min((x+\epsilon)-y,y-(x-\epsilon))$. It is easy to check that $\eta>0$, and $(y-\eta,y+\eta) \subset U \subset A$, hence $y \in A^\circ$, and so $U \subset A^\circ$.

Aside: The interior is often defined as the union of all open sets contained in $A$, and since the arbitrary union of open sets is open, it follows immediately, for this definition, that $A^\circ$ is open.