# Show that the interior of a set $S^0$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$S^0$  is the interior of a set $S$.

Let $x\in S^0$ be given. We want to find $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset S^0$.

$S^0$ is the interior of $S$, then $S^0\subset S$, then $x\in S$ and $\exists \delta_1>0$ such that $(x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1)\subset S$.

Can we say choose $\delta<\delta_1$  such that
$(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset(x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1)$,
then $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset S^0$,
therefore the interior of $S$ is open?

Does it make sense? Please guide me.

Comment: How do you find the interior of a set?

Comment: It is from the definition the first line.

Comment: @Omni: If you can state clearly what your definition of the interior of $S$ is then people can help you. Because this question can be answered in one line if you define the interior to be the largest open set contained in $S$.

Comment: That's not the definition that I have. Here is the one I have.S is open iff For every x belongs to S, there exist delta >0 such that ( x-delta, x+delta) subset of S

Comment: @Omni,no Ishfaaq is talking about the definition of the interior, not what an open set is.

Comment: It's almost the same as the open set but starts with the interior points are the set of all x belong to real numbers such that..... the rest like the open set.

Comment: I believe the interior set is all points $s \in S$ such that there exists an open ball around $s$ in $S$.

Comment: Judging from the argument that @Omni has posted, which is focused entirely on intervals and the real line, it seems safe to assume that this is an exercise that predates the definitions of a topological space, or even of metric spaces.  It seems that s/he is learning about the specific topological properties of the real line before generalizing them to more abstract spaces.  As a result, *interior* is being defined in real analysis terms rather than topological (or metric) terms.

Comment: Exactly the same question was asked a year ago:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347870/show-the-operatornameinta-is-open?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes perfect sense, but I can see that you might be slightly confused yourself.  I'll try and explain your own reasoning!

For $x$ to be in the interior of $X$, you need to show the existence of a $\delta$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq X$.  A set is open if it is its own interior, and you are trying to show that the interior of any set is always open.

So, what you have done is to show that every element of $S^{\circ}$ is an element of $\left(S^{\circ}\right)^{\circ}$.  You have taken an arbitrary element $x\in S^{\circ}$. Since it is in $S^{\circ}$, you know that there is a $\delta$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq S$.  So far so good.  But what we need to do is show that $x\in \left(S^{\circ}\right)^{\circ}$.  You have the right elements for this, but I'm not sure you quite know how to put them together.

You have done the right thing by taking $\delta_{1}\leq \delta$.  For simplicity, let's set $\delta_{1}=\delta/{2}$.  Then it will suffice to show that $(x-\delta_{1},x+\delta_{1})\subseteq S^{\circ}$.  So, take an arbitrary $y\in (x-\delta_{1},x+\delta_{1})$.  It follows that 
$$(y-\delta_{1},y+\delta_{1}) \subseteq (x-2\delta_{1},x+2\delta_{1}) = (x-\delta,x+\delta) \subseteq S.$$
But this is sufficient to show that $y\in S^{\circ}$.  There is therefore an open interval about $x$ which is contained in $S^{\circ}$, and so $x\in\left(S^{\circ}\right)^{\circ}$.  Since $x$ is an arbitrary element of $S$, we get 
$$S^{\circ}=\left(S^{\circ}\right)^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I just don't get why did you choose delta1= delta/2 and also the last part of your proof , I'm not sure what you did.

Comment: It wasn't necessary to choose $\delta_1=\delta/2$.  As you said, any $\delta_1<\delta$ would work.  In general, you would have to account for another term, $\delta_2$ satisfying $\delta_2\leq \delta-\delta_1$: Once you had chosen your $y\in (x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1)$, you could conclude that the interval $(y-\delta_2,y+\delta_2)$ is a subset of $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ by application of the triangle inequality.  Using $\delta_1=\delta/2$ means we can use $\delta_2=\delta_1$, which simplifies the argument.

Comment: We want to show that every $x\in S^{\circ}$ is an element of $\left(S^{\circ}\right)^{\circ}$. This means showing that for every such $x$, there is an open interval containing $x$ which is contained in $S^{\circ}$. This is our interval $(x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1)$.  We show that this interval is a subset of $S^{\circ}$ by showing that for every $y$ in it, there is an interval containing $y$ which is contained in $S$. This is the interval $(y-\delta_2,y+\delta_2)$. That this interval is indeed a subset of $S$ follows from our choice of $\delta$ and the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Treating the open interval $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$ as an open ball in the metric sense then $B(\varepsilon, x) := (x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$. So let x be any point in $Int(S)$, then there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(r,x)$ is  in $S$. Claim: $B(r/2, x)$ is contained in the $Int(S)$. Let y be any point in $B(r/2, x)$, then $B(r/2,y)$ is in $B(r, x)$. To see this, let $z$ be any point in $B(r/2, y)$, then $d(z,y) < r/2$ and $d(y,x) < r/2$. So $d(x,z) < d(x,y) + d(y,z) < r/2 + r/2 = r$. So $z$ belongs to $B(r, x)$. So 
$B(r/2, y)$ is in $B(r, x)$ and $B(r, x)$ is in $S$. So $B(r/2, y)$ is in $S$. This means $B(r/2, x)$ is in $Int(S)$. So $Int(S)$ is open.