# Finding Interior and Boundary Point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-analysis

$$U = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 < x_2 \leq 1\}$$

(a) Find all interior points of U. For each interior point, find a value of r for which the open ball lies inside U.

(b) Find all boundary points of U.

(c) Is U an open set? Is U a closed set? Why or why not?

So I know the definitions of boundary points and interior points but I'm not sure how to use the definitions of each to solve for this. First time attempting a problem like this, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Umm... you might want to retype what U is.  Right now I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: It is still not clear what $U$ is.

Comment: Can't seem to get the element of sign and the R^2 to work but I think it's readable now.

Answer (score 1):

[A drawing of the set U with interior and boundary points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sh6N.png)

The picture is a drawing of the set U (drawn in purple). The dashed line at $x_2=-1$ is not included in the set U, while the solid line $x_2=1$ is contained in U. Moreover, any point with $x_2$ strictly between -1 and 1 is contained in U. There are three points highlighted inside of U, namely w, y, and z.

Intuitively, y is in the interior of U. In order to show this mathematically, you can use the definition of an interior point that some open ball around y is contained in U. A ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ around y is of the form $B(y; \epsilon)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: \|x-y\|<\epsilon\}$ (in the picture, I drew such a ball). So if $y\in U$ is chosen so that $y_2\in (-1, 1)$, then you can choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that $B(y; \epsilon)\subseteq U$. You'll have to do a bit of work to find such an $\epsilon$.

On the other hand, w and z are on the boundary of U. To show this mathematically, you can use the definition of a boundary point showing that every ball around w or z touches a point in U and a point outside of U. Consider some ball $B(w; \epsilon)$ around $w$ with radius $\epsilon>0$ (in the picture, I drew an example). Note that, since $w_2 = -1$, any choice of $\epsilon$
will result in some point $q\in B(w; \epsilon)$ with $q_2 <-1$ and some point $r\in B(w; \epsilon)$ with $r_2>-1$. Hence $q\not\in U$ but $r\in U$. This shows that $w$ is on the boundary.

Comment: I have a similar diagram and I am using that to prove the boundary points and interior points, so I have that the interior of $$U = \{(x_1,x_2) \ | (-1 < x_1, x_2 < 1)}$$

Comment: Be careful. The interior of U is not $\{(x_1, x_2) : -1<x_1, x_2<1\}$. For example, the point $(1,0)$ looks to be in the interior of U although it does not fit this definition.

Instead, the interior of U is just $\{(x_1, x_2) : -1<x_2<1\}$.

Comment: Ah you're right, The origin is excluded from the interior points correct? So I guess I can't really use the picture but I'll have to find an $epsilon$ and go from there.

Comment: Having some trouble figuring out the value of $epsilon$, any hints?

Comment: No, the origin is an interior point. I'll show you why and perhaps that will help you prove something about the interior.

Let $y = (0,0)$ and take $\epsilon = 1/2$. I claim that $B(y; \epsilon)\subseteq U$. So take some point in $x\in B(y; \epsilon)$. In order to show that $x\in U$, we need to show that $-1<x_2\leq 1$. By the definition of $y, \epsilon$ and $B(y; \epsilon)$, we have

$$\|x-y\| =|(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2|  = (x_1)^2+(x_2)^2 < \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}.$$

So it must be the case that $-1<x_2\leq 1$ because otherwise the inequality above would be false.

Comment: So if I can show that (x1,1) and (x1, -1) are greater than epsilon then I have proven that all the interior points are between 1 and -1?

Comment: Again, you must be careful. We are claiming that
$$interior(U) = \{(x_1, x_2): -1<x_2< 1\}.$$
Observe that the definition of the interior of U does not rely on $x_1$. So in order to prove our claim, the proof should look like this....

First we will show that $interior(U) \supseteq \{(x_1, x_2): -1<x_2< 1\}$. Let $(x_1, x_2)\in  \{(x_1, x_2): -1<x_2<1\}$. Since $-1<x_2< 1$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $-1<x_2-\epsilon < x_2+\epsilon\leq 1$. In order to show that $(x_1, x_2)\in interior(U)$, it is enough to show that $B((x_1, x_2); \epsilon)\subseteq U$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it is enough to show that $B((x_1,x_2), \sqrt{\epsilon})\subseteq U$. 

So take $(q_1, q_2)\in B((x_1, x_2);\sqrt{\epsilon})$. This implies that
$$\sqrt{|q_2-x_2|} \leq \sqrt{|q_2-x_2|+|q_1-x_1|} = \|x-q\| <\sqrt{\epsilon}$$
Therefore, $|q_2-x_2|<\epsilon$. Hence, $-1<x_2-\epsilon<q_2<x_2+\epsilon\leq 1$. By the definition of $U$, we see that $(q_1, q_2)$ is therefore inside of $U$. Hence $ B((x_1, x_2);\sqrt{\epsilon})\subseteq U$. By the definition of interior of U, we have that $(q_1, q_2)$ is in the interior of U

Comment: Oh, I was completely off. I trying to show that x1 is also part of the boundary. If I understand your explanation correctly, I pick 2 random points, take their distance from x1,x2 and then show that the norm of those points is less than an arbitrary epsilon and that would be enough?

Comment: You are on the right track, but again we need to be careful. To start, in this question note that one point is of the form $(x_1, x_2)$. That is, a point has two coordinates. So neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ is a point. 
In order to prove that $\{(x_1, x_2):-1<x_2<1\}\subseteq interior(U)$, we must take the following steps:

1. Take an arbitrary $(q_1, q_2)\in\{(x_1, x_2):-1<x_2<1\}$. 
2. Find some $\epsilon>0$ so that $B((q_1, q_2); \epsilon)\subseteq U$. Note that $\epsilon$ will most likely depend on the point $(q_1, q_2)$.

In the previous message, I did not specify $\epsilon$.

Comment: Can't I also just choose an arbitrary epsilon as well? And then prove that the norm from (x,y)-(q1,q2) is less than it? The more I understand this the more confused I get. I am having a lot of difficulty as my textbook does not have any examples or a similar question to this so I am king of just going in blind.

Comment: Let me give an example. I hope this helps.

Ex. Let $U = \{(x_1, x_2): x_2\leq 1\}$. Show $interior(U) = \{(x_1, x_2): x_2<1\}$.
Solution: Let $(q_1, q_2)\in \{(x_1, x_2): x_2<1\}$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{1-q_2}{2}$. Note that $\epsilon>0$ since $q_2<1$ and $q_2+\epsilon <1$. Consider $B((q_1, q_2), \sqrt{\epsilon})$ -- we want to show this ball is in U. So we need to show for any $(w_1, w_2)\in B((q_1, q_2), \epsilon)$, that $w_2\leq 1$. Note $|q_2-w_2|\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}$ and so $w_2<q_2+\epsilon<1$. Hence $(w_1, w_2)\in U$ and $B((q_1, q_2), \sqrt{\epsilon})\subseteq interior(U)$.

Comment: Here is another example:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684420/show-that-the-interior-of-a-set-s0-is-open

Comment: So can I make my $epsilon$ either 1+q or 1-q? Or is there any restriction on that?

Comment: Also thanks for the example, it's clearing some confusions up.

Comment: There is no restriction on what you make $\epsilon$